# Cómo implementar de forma correcta con Entity Framework (Database First) y ViewModels; Clave Foránea (Columnas "Ids" - FK)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

estoy usando **Entity Framework** con **database first** y a la vez uso los **"View Models"**, pero al estar implementando se generó una duda para implementar de forma correcta.

Un ejemplo básico para la explicación...

1. **Tablas**

   ```
   Prenda:
    - Id (PK)
    - Nombre
    - IdTipoPrenda (FK)

   TipoPrenda:
    - Id (PK)
    - Nombre
   ```
2. **Clases**

   ```
   public class Prenda {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Nombre { get; set; }
     public int IdTipoPrenda { get; set; }

     public virtual TipoPrenda TipoPrenda { get; set; }
   }

   public class TipoPrenda {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Nombre { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. **Uso**

   Cuando quiero asignar el **Id** en mi **ViewModel**, tengo **dos opciones** y no sé cual sería la forma apropiada de hacerlo.

   ```
   var prendasDB = dbContext.Prenda.Include("TipoPrenda").ToList();
   var prendasVM = new List<PrendaViewModel>();

   foreach (var prenda in prendasDB) {
     var prendaVM = new PrendaViewModel {
       Id = prenda.Id,
       Nombre = prenda.Nombre,
       //IdTipoPrenda = prenda.IdTipoPrenda ó prenda.TipoPrenda.Id
     }
     prendasVM.Add(prendaVM );
   }
   ```

   La primera opción sería usar el atributo **IdTipoPrenda** que se crea por la propia columna de la tabla, y la segunda opción sería usar la **relación** que se generá por la conexión de clave foránea (FK).

***¿Hacer uso de cualquier opción que diferencias (así sean las mínimas) generaría? y si no las hay ¿Cuál sería la forma correcta de implementar esta parte?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ambas Opciones que mencionas son validas, ya que están relacionadas por el Id de TipoPrenda y retorna el mismo id.

Por otra parte si en tu viewModel no necesitas mas que el Id de tipoPrenda, esta de mas que incluyas la relacion `.Include("TipoPrenda")` ya que el Id de Tipo Prenda ya lo tienes en la entidad Prenda.